# How to Set the Properties of an Member that is also a Class?

Tags: c#, reflection

this what I want to do, I don't know if it is possible or maybe I have been attacking the problem in an incorrect way:

I have an object whose member have a custom attribute, I am using the info in that attribute to search for a value in a collection and then, with reflection, set the value for that given property. But my type has some more complex members, member that are not a simple string or int, but are classes that also have the attribute with the info to set their values.

So, to set the value using reflection, I need the instance of the object that I am altering, so my question is:

how do I get the actual member so I can inspect and get their values using the attributes that they have?

Here some sample code of what I have and what I want:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [CustomAttribute("Info to Set Values")]
    public string SimpleProperty {get;set;}

    public MyOtherClass ComplexProperty {get;set;}

    public static bool SetSimpleValueTypes(object instance, IEnumerable<Value> values){
        var mappedProperties = instance.GetType()
                                   .GetProperties()
                                   .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttribute), true).Length > 0);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in mappedProperties)
        {
           /*...and then some code to get the Value to set in the property*/
           var value = GetValue(values);
           property.SetValue(instance, value, null);
        }
    }

}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    [CustomAttribute("Info to Set Values")]
    public string SimpleInnerProperty {get;set;}
}
```

In the code above, in the method SetSimpleValueTypes, I get all the properties of a given instance that have properties with the CustomAttribute, then I iterate those PropertyInfo and set the value using the instance that I pass to it; I would use it as follows:

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
MyEntity.SetSimpleValueTypes(entity, valuesFromSomeWhere);
```

That will correctly set the values for all the properties that are simple types: string, int, and the such; but now, I also need to set the values in ComplexProperty so, using a not so flexible approach, I could this:

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
MyEntity.SetSimpleValueTypes(entity, valuesFromSomeWhere);
MyEntity.SetSimpleValueTypes(entity.ComplexProperty, valuesFromSomeWhere);
```

So, want I really want to do is to, instead of calling explicitly the ComplexProperty to pass it to the SetSimpleValueTypes method, I would like to iterate throw the properties of MyEntity and when a complex value is found, pass the actual instance of the complex type to the method so it can iterate its properties and set their values in that instance.

Hope this can clarify the question a little more. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As it is written, your MyEntity object will probably not have the `ComplexProperty` populated when your method runs, right? It will just be null. So you'll have to create a new instance of `MyOtherClass` (using `Activator.CreateInstance()` for example, or maybe a DI framework), and then recursively call your method on that object as well.

```
public static bool SetValueTypes(object instance, IEnumerable<Value> values){
    var mappedProperties = instance.GetType()
                               .GetProperties()
                               .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttribute), true).Length > 0);

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in mappedProperties)
    {
       /*...and then some code to get the Value to set in the property*/
       var value = GetValue(values);
       property.SetValue(instance, value, null);
    }

    var complexProperties = instance.GetType()
                               .GetProperties()
    // Either assume that unmapped properties are all complex,
    // or use your own criteria. Maybe anything whose type is
    // a class and not a string?
                               .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttribute), true).Length == 0);
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in mappedProperties)
    {
       var value = Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
       SetValueTypes(value, values);
       property.SetValue(instance, value, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well yeah, but that is becasue I was assuming that it was clear code is just the hierarchy I am trying to navigate.

Comment: @Hugo: I don't understand your comment. And if you would like a more detailed answer, you'll probably need to include the reflection code you already have in the question. I can't tell what part of this you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Just added more code and comments, I hope could me my question clearer =)

Comment: @Hugo: I added a code sample. It may not compile, or be exactly what you want, but hopefully it will put you on the right path.